# How do I style the first row of every table on the page using jQuery

Tags: jquery, css, html-table

I need to manually style the first row of every table on a page. Unfortunately I'm dealing with some old browsers so would like to do this via jQuery.

Currently I'm using:

```
$(function() {
 $(".OpenCourse tr:first").addClass("OpenCoursesHeader");
});
```

then adding `.OpenCoursesHeader td {}` to style.

the class `OpenCoursesHeader` only seems to be applied to the first table.

Any ideas how I get it to apply to the second? There will always only be two tables on the page if that makes it simpler.

Comment: Apply a common CSS class to your tables... My guess is that the second table does not have the class `.OpenCourse`.

Answer (score 3):

You could use the `first-child` selector.
`first` will only select the first element of the selector you're working with.

```
$(function() {
 $(".OpenCourse tr:first-child").addClass("OpenCoursesHeader");
});
```

But if you have nested tables, this solution will also add the class to the first `tr`.

Comment: Still suffers from the same issue as mine when multiple `thead`/`tbody`s are concerned - [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ult_combo/bUqPX/3/), in which case I'd prefer Vision's solution.

Comment: @FabrícioMatté True. I've pointed out the problem with nested tables but didn't think about thead/tbody. Good point!

Comment: If I remember correctly, `:first` isn't necessarily the first on the page, just the first in whatever set is currently being worked with (in this case all `tr` children of `.OpenCourse` elements)

Answer (score 1):

You may use [`find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/) and it will work:

```
$(".OpenCourse").find("tr:first").addClass("OpenCoursesHeader");
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/bUqPX/1/ -- *thanks to [Fabrício](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12938549/1249581) :)*

Comment: Looks good, +1 because this is more bulletproof than mine in case thead/tbody elements are used. `=]`

Answer (score 1):

```
$(function() {
    $(".OpenCourse tr:nth-child(1)").addClass("OpenCoursesHeader");
});
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ult_combo/bUqPX/)

[`:nth-child() selector` Reference](http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/)

Or you can use the [`:first-child` selector](http://api.jquery.com/first-child-selector/) as answered by @ComputerArts, which is equivalent to `:nth-child(1)` as per [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/first-child-selector/).

Also, this may not work properly if you have `<thead>`/`<tbody>`/`<tfooter>` elements, in that case you must specify the one you want to apply the styling to in the selector as well:

```
$(".OpenCourse thead:nth-child(1) tr:nth-child(1)").addClass("OpenCoursesHeader");
```

Comment: doesnt seemed to have worked at all, the first tables lost styling now.

Comment: Well if none of your answers work, update the fiddle to reproduce your problem, I'll be afk now but will look it up later as soon as I can.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(function() {  
     $("table tr:first").addClass("OpenCoursesHeader"); 
});
```

This will apply to all tables on the page. Hope this Helps!!

Comment: i have to limit it to .OpenCourses as theirs other table stylings

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function() {
    $(".OpenCourse").each(function() {
        $("tr:first",this).addClass("OpenCoursesHeader");
    });
});
```

Give that a try, is there a page with the code on that we can look at?

Answer (score 0):

Select `table` first and do a `find` on `tr:first`.

Below is assuming that `OpenCourse` is a container for collection of tables..

```
$(".OpenCourse table").find("tr:first").addClass("OpenCoursesHeader");
```

If `OpenCourse` is the class of the table then try [@Vision](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12938544/297641)'s answer