# Jquery add css class to the first row of a table

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to add a css class to the first tr of a table using jquery. I know this should be super easy, I found a lot of links and questions that provide correct solutions. Like these three and others:

[How to get the id of first <tr> of <tbody> in HTML table using jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23465602/how-to-get-the-id-of-first-tr-of-tbody-in-html-table-using-jquery)

[JQuery, select first row of table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6924333/jquery-select-first-row-of-table)

[How do I style the first row of every table on the page using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12938510/how-do-i-style-the-first-row-of-every-table-on-the-page-using-jquery)

But for me none of these works.

I have a table with id DataTableMovimenti and I want to apply the css class "ct-active"

I tried the following instructions:

```
$("#DataTableMovimenti tr:first").addClass('ct-active');
$("#DataTableMovimenti").find("tr:first-children").addClass("ct-active");
$("#DataTableMovimenti").find("tr:first").addClass("ct-active");
$("#DataTableMovimenti").find("tr:eq(0)").addClass("ct-active");
$("#DataTableMovimenti").find("tbody tr:eq(0)").addClass("ct-active");
$("#DataTableMovimenti").children("tr:first").addClass("ct-active");
$("#DataTableMovimenti").closest('tr').addClass('ct-active');
```

I inserted the code in the `$document.ready()` function in my jsp, because I want highlight the first row of the table when I enter the page.

The table have this structure:

```
<table id="DataTableMovimenti" class="table ct-datatables">
<thead>
   <tr></tr>
      ............
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr id="tableRowId" class="table-row-tr"></tr>
      ...........
</tbody>
</table>
```

I want to change the css class of the first tr in the tbody section.

Comment: Your first line should work fine - although CSS would be a better option. Have you checked the console for errors, and are you running your code in a DOMReady handler?

Comment: `$("#DataTableMovimenti tbody > tr:first-child").addClass('ct-active');`

Comment: You can directly use CSS to do that `#DataTableMovimenti tr:first-child`

Comment: @Pugazh your suggestion might work if the class being added is ONLY for the purpose of styling. A classname might also be used for other purposes.

Comment: I know one of the lines i tried should work, as @Huelfe solution, but i don't know why they doesn't. And i haven't error in console. I accepted the css solution. That worked well! Thank you all

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add `tbody` in your selector.

```js
$("#DataTableMovimenti tbody tr:first").addClass('ct-active');
```

```css
.ct-active{
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="DataTableMovimenti">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td>First thead</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>First tbody</td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
       <td>Second tbody</td>
     </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

It's better to do that with **css**.

```css
#DataTableMovimenti tbody > tr:first-child {
  color:red;
 }
```

```html
    <table id="DataTableMovimenti">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <td>First thead</td>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>First tbody</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Second tbody</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
```

Comment: thank you @Alexis your css solution works for me. It's really strange because none of the jquery solutions, that i know are correct, works for me.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
$('#DataTableMovimenti tbody tr:first-child').addClass('ct-active');
```

Answer (score 1):

The *:first* pseudo-class is equivalent to *:eq( 0 )*. It could also be written as *:lt( 1 )*. While this matches only a single element, *:first-child* can match more than one: One for each parent.

**Additional Notes:**

Because *:first* is a jQuery extension and not part of the CSS specification, queries using :first cannot take advantage of the performance boost provided by the native DOM *querySelectorAll()* method. To achieve the best performance when using *:first* to select elements, first select the elements using a pure CSS selector, then use *.filter(":first")*.
Selected elements are in the order of their appearance in the document.For example:

```
$("table tr:first").addClass('yourclass-name');
```

Or for a specific table:

```
$("#myTable tr:first").addClass('yourclass-name');
```

```js
$("tr:first").addClass("demo-class");
```

```css
td {
  color: blue;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.demo-class {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>first demo</title>
</head>

<body>

  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>Row 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row 3</td>
    </tr>
  </table>


</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a jQuery pseudo-selector called [`:first`](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/sel_first.asp) which is like CSS `:first-of-type` or `:first-child`, the difference being that `:first` will pick only **THE** first element and not every element that meets a criteria of being the first child of it's parent. BTW, when dealing with tables, it might be best to specify `<tbody>` in your selector, otherwise you'll end up targeting the `<tr>` in `<thead>`.

```js
$(function() {
  $('#DataTableMovimenti tbody tr:first').removeClass("table-row-tr").addClass("table-row-tr-Active");
});
```

```css
.table-row-tr-Active {
  background: red;
}
table {
  width: 200px;
}
table,
td {
  border: 2px solid grey;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table id="DataTableMovimenti" class="table ct-datatables">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td>HEADER</td>
    </tr>

  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr id="tableRowId" class="table-row-tr">
      <td>CELL</td>
    </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Best way to do this is to use pseudo-selector :first.

```
$('#DataTableMovimenti tbody tr:first').addClass('active');
```